# React: две формы на одной странице, одна из форм не работает

Tags: reactjs

Для логина и регистрации на сайт сделал одну страницу - в ней две формы, которые переключаются в TAB.
Во всем приложении нет никаких ошибок.
Логин работает без ошибок.
Регистрация не работает - я попадаю в стрелочную функцию onSubmitRegister - отрабатывает console.log в котором видно, что данные из формы корректно собраны и переданы. Но дальше ничего не происходит:
проверка соответствия паролей не срабатывает, функция signup не вызывается

Все названия аргументов и функций двух форм разведены, конфликтов нет, ошибок никаких не выдается. Просто не отрабатывает импортированная функция signup.

Это код страницы Логин-Регистрация:

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import React, {Fragment, useState} from "react"
import MetaTags from "react-meta-tags"
import {Redirect, Link} from "react-router-dom"
import {BreadcrumbsItem} from "react-breadcrumbs-dynamic"
import Tab from "react-bootstrap/Tab"
import Nav from "react-bootstrap/Nav"
import Breadcrumb from "./Layout/Breadcrumb"
import {login, signup} from "../../redux/actions/authActions"
import {setAlert} from "../../redux/actions/alertActions"
import {connect} from "react-redux"
import {multilanguage} from "redux-multilanguage"

const LoginRegister = ({strings, location, login, isAuthenticated}) => {
    const {pathname} = location
    const [accountCreated, setAccountCreated] = useState(false)

    // LOGIN HANDLING
    const [loginFormData, setLoginFormData] = useState({
        logemail: '',
        logpassword: ''
    })
    const {logemail, logpassword} = loginFormData
    const onChangeLogin = e => setLoginFormData({...loginFormData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    const onSubmitLogin = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        login(logemail, logpassword)
    }

    // REGISTER HANDLING
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        email: '',
        name: '',
        password: '',
        re_password: ''
    })
    const {email, name, password, re_password} = formData
    const onChangeRegister = e => setFormData({...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})

    const onSubmitRegister = e => {
        console.log('Submit: ', email, name, password, re_password)
        e.preventDefault()
        if (password !== re_password)
            setAlert('Passwords do not match', 'error')
        else
            signup({name, email, password, re_password})
        setAccountCreated(true)
    }

    if (isAuthenticated || accountCreated)
        return <Redirect to="/about"/>

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <MetaTags>
                <title> | Login - Register</title>
                <meta
                    name="description"
                    content={strings['description']}
                />
            </MetaTags>

            <BreadcrumbsItem to={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/"}>{strings["home"]}</BreadcrumbsItem>
            <BreadcrumbsItem to={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + pathname}>{strings["login_register"]}</BreadcrumbsItem>

            <Breadcrumb/>

            <div className="login-register-area pt-100 pb-100">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-lg-7 col-md-12 ml-auto mr-auto">
                            <div className="login-register-wrapper">
                                <Tab.Container defaultActiveKey="login">
                                    <Nav variant="pills" className="login-register-tab-list">
                                        <Nav.Item>
                                            <Nav.Link eventKey="login">
                                                <h4>{strings["login"]}</h4>
                                            </Nav.Link>
                                        </Nav.Item>
                                        <Nav.Item>
                                            <Nav.Link eventKey="register">
                                                <h4>{strings["register"]}</h4>
                                            </Nav.Link>
                                        </Nav.Item>
                                    </Nav>
                                    <Tab.Content>
                                        <Tab.Pane eventKey="login">
                                            <div className="login-form-container">
                                                <div className="login-register-form">
                                                    <form onSubmit={e => onSubmitLogin(e)}>
                                                        <input
                                                            placeholder={strings["email"]}
                                                            name="logemail"
                                                            value={logemail}
                                                            type="email"
                                                            onChange={e => onChangeLogin(e)}
                                                            required
                                                        />
                                                        <input
                                                            placeholder={strings["password"]}
                                                            name="logpassword"
                                                            value={logpassword}
                                                            type="password"
                                                            onChange={e => onChangeLogin(e)}
                                                            required
                                                            minLength="6"
                                                        />
                                                        <div className="button-box">
                                                            <div className="login-toggle-btn">
                                                                <input type="checkbox"/>
                                                                <label className="ml-10">{strings["remember_me"]}</label>
                                                                <Link to={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/"}>{strings["forgot_password"]}</Link>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <button type="submit">
                                                                <span>{strings["login"]}</span>
                                                            </button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </form>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </Tab.Pane>
                                        <Tab.Pane eventKey="register">
                                            <div className="login-form-container">
                                                <div className="login-register-form">
                                                    <form onSubmit={e => onSubmitRegister(e)}>
                                                        <input
                                                            placeholder={strings["name"]}
                                                            name="name"
                                                            value={name}
                                                            type="text"
                                                            onChange={e => onChangeRegister(e)}
                                                            required
                                                        />
                                                        <input
                                                            placeholder={strings["email"]}
                                                            name="email"
                                                            value={email}
                                                            type="email"
                                                            onChange={e => onChangeRegister(e)}
                                                            required
                                                        />
                                                        <input
                                                            placeholder={strings["password"] + " - " + strings["minimum_6_characters"]}
                                                            type="password"
                                                            name="password"
                                                            value={password}
                                                            onChange={e => onChangeRegister(e)}
                                                            required
                                                        />
                                                        <input
                                                            placeholder={strings["retype_the_password"]}
                                                            type="password"
                                                            name="re_password"
                                                            value={re_password}
                                                            onChange={e => onChangeRegister(e)}
                                                            required
                                                        />
                                                        <div className="button-box">
                                                            <button type="submit">
                                                                <span>{strings["register"]}</span>
                                                            </button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </form>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </Tab.Pane>
                                    </Tab.Content>
                                </Tab.Container>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

LoginRegister.propTypes = {
    location: PropTypes.object,
    strings: PropTypes.object
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.authReducer.isAuthenticated
})

export default multilanguage(connect(mapStateToProps, {login, signup, setAlert})(LoginRegister))
```

Это импортируемая функция signup:

```
export const signup = ({email, name, password, re_password}) => async dispatch => {
    console.log(`signup job: ${email}`, name, password, re_password)
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }

    const body = JSON.stringify({ email, name, password, re_password })

    try {
        const res = await axios.post(`https://some-domain.com/auth/users/`, body, config)

        dispatch({
            type: SIGNUP_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        });
        dispatch(setAlert('Successful registration', 'success'))
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: SIGNUP_FAIL
        })
        dispatch(setAlert(`Error during registration ${err}`, 'error'))
    }
}
```

Это login такой же как signup - только работает нормально:

```
export const login = (email, password) => async dispatch => {
    console.log(email, password)

    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });
    console.log(config, body)
    try {
        const res = await axios.post(`https://some-domain/auth/jwt/create/`, body, config);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        });

        dispatch(load_user());
        dispatch(setAlert('Successful authorization', 'success'));
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_FAIL
        });
        dispatch(setAlert('Invalid email or password', 'error'));
    }
}
```

Явно не вижу чего-то простого и важного... помогите разобраться)

Comment: у вас signup возвращает функцию которую никто не вызывает

Comment: вызываю signup ровно так же, как и login - при этом login отрабатывает норм. пытался вынести signup из условия, тоже ничего не получилось.

Comment: вы не деструктуризировали signup в 'const LoginRegister = ({strings, location, login, isAuthenticated}) => {...'  и он у вас выполняется как импортированный action

Comment: всё верно, деструктуризировал и всё заработало. Спасибо, Евгений